# Built-in binary operator * cannot be applied

Tags: solidity

I have this piece of code:

```
int24 tickSpacing = ...

uint8 numTicks = ...
for (uint8 i = 0; i < numTicks; i++) {

    int24 step = tickSpacing * i;

...
```

At this code I receive: `Built-in binary operator * cannot be applied to types int24 and uint8.`

I also tried: `int24 step = int24(tickSpacing) * int24(i);`

But is giving this error: `Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint8" to "int24".`

How I can do that simple multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity currently (v0.8) doesn't allow implicit conversion between `uint` (unsigned integer, without +- sign) and `int` (signed integer, with +- sign), so you need to convert it explicitly.

The conversion is needed to be able to multiply the two numbers. Otherwise you'd be multiplying two different types (`uint` and `int`), which is not permitted.

```
// explicitly convert `i` from `uint8` to `int8`
int24 step = tickSpacing * int8(i);
```